# Bulk sms sending

Tags: sms

Is there any suggestions on how we can send bulk sms in ubuntu? I need it for my business. If anyone knows how we can send bulk sms in the ubuntu software just tell me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used these software personally, but from a basic search on the internet, I was able to find these:

- [FrontlineSMS](http://www.frontlinesms.com/)
- [playSMS](http://playsms.org/)
- [Gammu/Wammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/)
- [Spring Edge](https://www.springedge.com/)
- [Kalkun](http://kalkun.sourceforge.net/)